# Question about Span & Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What does {$(1,2,3),(-2,0,4),(-1,2,7)$} span and find its basis ?

I form a matrix and reduce to echelon form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 1 & \frac{5}{2}\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Does this mean the basis is {$(1,2,3),(0,1,\frac{5}{2})$}?

The basis is $2$ dimensional and so spans a plane in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: If you did the calculations correctly, the answer is yes. When you apply Gauss-Jordan elimination, the span doesn't change.

Comment: @Zima Okay that works, thank you

Comment: Let $\{\underbrace{(1,2,3)}_{v_1},\underbrace{(-2,0,4)}_{v_2},\underbrace{(-1,2,7)}_{v_2} \}$, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&-1&x \\2&0&2&y \\3&4&7&z \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow  \begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&-1&x \\0&1&1&(y-2x)/4 \\0&0&0&(8x-10y+4z)/40 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
The plane is $4z−10y+8x=0$, so yes it does span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{ v_1,v_2\}$ given that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent.